# How to access one form's property from another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 WinForms, in **Form1** I declared this:

```
public int NumberOfContacts { get; set; }
```

I need to access that property from **Form2**.

Comment: In this case either form1 will need a reference to form2 or vice versa.  If one creates the other the natural thing to do is give the created value a reference to the parent from which it can read the necessary values

Comment: You could add a little more detail to the question; does the 2nd form need to be notified when the value changes realtime? If so, you could use an event. If it just needs to pull the value, what @JaredPar suggested will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a usual question concerning acceding a Form's member from an other form, I will assume that you want to access NumberOfContacts from the currect active instance of Form1, in that case you would simply , and just as you did declare in your :

**Form1** :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int NumberOfContacts { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

and in **Form2** :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // ActiveForm will give you access to the current opened/activated Form1 instance
            var numberOfContacts  = ((Form1) Form1.ActiveForm).NumberOfContacts;
        }
    }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

When opening your `Form2` use this code:

```
Form2 f2  = new Form2();
f2.Show(this);
```

And in your `Form2:`

```
var value = ((Form1)Owner).NumberOfContacts;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have created an instance of form2 from form1, you can set it like this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.NumberfOfContacts = this.NumberOfContacts;
form2.Show();
```

You can also pass the value of form1.NumberOfContacts to the constructor of form2 like this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this.NumberOfContacts);
form2.Show();
```

Form2 class:

```
public int NumberOfContacts { get; set; }

public Form2(int numberOfContacts)
{
    NumberOfContacts = numberOfContacts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access and change another form properties you can use this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm_main frmmain = new frm_main();
    frmmain.Visible = true;
    frmmain.Enabled = true;
}
```