# How to access an array of another form in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

I've just started learning how to code in C# and I'm trying to make a program that should help learning french vocabulary.

Since I'm not good in SQL-Databases yet, I'm using a VocabArray and a TransArray to define the vocabulary.

In the next step, I want to add a new word. I'm doing that through two text boxes that should add their string to the array in the main form. But how do I access the array from the main form through the textboxes in my new form?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [How to access one form's property from another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022854/how-to-access-one-forms-property-from-another)

Comment: Just FYI: C# has a [Dictionary<Key, Value>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) that might be more suitable for your program than two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact an array doesn't really support your purpose (`Dictionary<string, string>` or `List<Tuple<string, string>>` would be better)
You can just make a static variable like so:
`internal static string[] arr = {"something", "something else"};`
Put this in the class but outside the methods